# Drawing lines on the last canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am new to javascript and canvas programming.
I have a function drawLines(canvasIndex,startPosition) which is responsible for drawing lines on a canvas. It takes in two arguments canvasIndex which represents the canvas which I am drawing on and startPosition represents the starting point of the line. Now I am calling the function in my code. The below shows the way in which I am calling the function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function drawLines(canvasIndex,startPosition)
{
...
}
drawLines(0,0);
drawLines(1,0);
</script>
```

Now during the execution, the lines are drawn only on the last canvasIndex specified. Meaning, if I call it in this sequence,

```
drawLines(0,0);
drawLines(2,0);
```

it draws the lines only on the second canvas and not sequentially. I want it to be such that it draws sequentially by just this sort of function calls. Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/drFV4/

**First, create an array to hold your canvas contexts:**

var contexts=[];

**Then get references to your canvas elements and create contexts for them.**

Put the contexts in the contexts array:

```
HTML:

<canvas id="canvas0" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas1" width=100 height=100></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" width=100 height=100></canvas>

JavaScript:

var canvas0=document.getElementById("canvas0");
contexts.push(canvas0.getContext("2d"));
var canvas1=document.getElementById("canvas1");
contexts.push(canvas1.getContext("2d"));
var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas2");
contexts.push(canvas2.getContext("2d"));
```

**Create your drawLines function:**

```
function drawLines(canvasIndex,startPosition){
    var ctx=contexts[canvasIndex];
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(startPosition,10);
    ctx.lineTo(50,50);
    ctx.lineWidth=5;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

**Finally, call your function as desired:**

```
drawLines(0,0);
drawLines(1,50);
drawLines(2,100);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! One quick question, was the problem because of "Closure in a loop" in javascript? Or was it that it could not get the references?

Comment: You're welcome!  Difficult to say why the last canvas was getting all the drawings without seeing more of your code.  I suspect since the drawing was being done--but on the wrong canvas, that scoping  (closures) was not your issue.